# wanting to know why a question is off topic

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[is this optional keyword redundant?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/52520/15922)

That's my question. It looks about as on-topic as this question:

[ASN.1: ENUMERATED vs INTEGER](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/22586/15922)

The ASN.1: ENUMERATED vs INTEGER wasn't closed, however, so why was mine?

Answer (score 2):

I closed this one as it is not a security question. The decision to put that comment in may be answerable by the original developer.

The other question you reference would probably have been closed if it was asked now, as the requirements have matured as the site has grown.

Comment: I realize this is an old question but...  is there any SE place where this would be an on-topic question in your mind? Would crypto.stackexchange.com be a better place for the question I asked? I don't see ASN1 / DER as being strictly crypto but ASN1 / DER is mainly utilized for crypto applications. Or maybe stackoverflow.com would be a better venue? Or maybe there's no good place, currently, for ASN1 / DER related questions?

Comment: You could try it on crypto, however the reason it is off topic is not because it is about ASN, but because it is about a decision made by the developers of that code.